# Can I sync my KOrganizer and iCloud calendars?

Tags: kde, calendar, kontact

Is there a way for a busy person to be able to put an item on my iCloud Calendar and have the event added to a main KOrganizer calendar automatically, and vice versa?

Comment: I don't think there's an iCloud Sync for Linux.  In Windows this is done with its own executables.

Comment: Yes. iCloud has caldav support. You can use kOrganizer to add any caldav account. To do that you will need iCloud caldav calendar url. See this topic https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=81241

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I did this, thanks to the advice from @Khurshid_Alam:

1. Download an iCloud CloudDav discovery program called `icloud`
   from [its GitHub page](https://github.com/muhlba91/icloud).
2. Extract `icloud-master/groovy_java/gui-2.0.1.zip`. (Be sure to read the README as apparently there are legal issues...)
3. Run `icloud-master/groovy_java/gui-2.0.1/bin/gui`.
4. Type in Apple ID Credentials and select a server. Any server will work. Click "Get calendar URLs".
5. Click the URL on the far right next to the name of the main Calendar, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.
6. In KOrganizer, right click your calendar folder display (by default it is on the bottom left) and select Add Calendar.
7. Click "DAV Groupware Resource". Enter in your Apple ID credentials, select the "Configure the resource manually".
8. Allow access to the wallet, if the window comes up, and if applicable.
9. A new window will come up with "Server configuration" at the bottom. Click "Add" to the right of it, paste the copied URL into the "Remote URL" box, and click "Fetch". When you click "OK", the calendar will be added and automatic uploading and downloading of calendar data will be possible.
10. Have fun!

Comment: If you have 2FA, check this link: https://github.com/muhlba91/icloud/issues/12

Comment: The linked utility appears to be abandoned and no longer returns calendar URLs.

Comment: I began on step #4 and it worked fine for me, and I have 2FA, just used the URL: https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com and my login from step #4, and it pulled in all my stuff. It worked like a charm. I found the URL by clicking the WiFi icon in iCloud. It gives you an option to make the calendar public and I used the first part of that URL.

Answer (score 1):

This worked in August 2019:

1. Open your Calendar App on iCloud.com or iPhone
2. Make calendar public to check the direct link to the server. It might looks like these:

   https://**p15**-caldav.icloud.com

   https://**p16**-caldav.icloud.com

   etc...
3. Calendar doesn't need to be public anymore. Make calendar private again if you wish.
4. Go to https://appleid.apple.com and generate password for third-party application. Label it as 'KOrganizer'.
5. Open KOrganizer, Add Calendar as "DAV Groupware Resource". Enter in your Apple ID, generated password and select the "Configure the resource manually".
6. Add url from step 2. This link will add all calendars from icloud. It is possible to sync only selected calendars.

Comment: Links in this format are not valid anymore:
https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com/<DSid>/calendars/<pGUID>

Comment: I just followed all these steps but used the URL: https://pXX-caldav.icloud.com and my login from step #4, and it pulled in all my stuff. It worked like a charm. It seemed to convert the https url to http and tack on the secure port 443, but it was my first time using KOrganizer. Worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

Right now I can verify that KOrganizer is not sending authorization headers:

See [this post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=215&t=165265&p=448123#p448123) on [Sync with icloud Caldav](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=215&t=165265&sid=84088505d6a124ef76cc9af695ab7e68)

> There is a bug open for this, but no action in 6 months:
>
> https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=434757

Answer (score 1):

Since this thread is highly ranked on Google, I'll add a new reply despite it being quite old. I've [fixed this issue](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kdav/-/merge_requests/16) and it should be working with the next release of `kdav` (presumably > `v5.90.0`).

The accepted change in [KDav - GitLab](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kdav/-/tree/master) fixed an error in the usage of the calendar-multiget retrieval As documented in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4791#section-7.9 , ics files inside the request are referenced via their relative path. The change corrects this behavior. This is what was preventing KDav from working with iCloud.