# How to sync icloud calendar to GNOME?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, apple, calendar

I have to use Apple devices at work. All the calendar events are using icloud and its share with colleagues. So is there a way to sync icloud with my Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome?

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539893/can-i-sync-my-korganizer-and-icloud-calendars)

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539893/can-i-sync-my-korganizer-and-icloud-calendars)

Comment: icloud has caldav support. You can install evolution and then add  icloud calendars with caldav link.  Does this help?

Comment: You can sync GNOME with iCloud [using CalDAV](https://www.slightfuture.com/technote/gnome-caldav).

Comment: I quit my job there, so I dont use apple any more! Thanks for support